# Numerical Differentiation, 3 point formula

Tags: derivatives

How do I find the relative error of approximation of $f'(6)$ by the 3-point symmetric formula with mesh size $h = 0.05$, where $f(x) = 4/(1+3x^2)$?

Answer (score 1):

The 3-point symmetric expression for the derivative is

$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + h) - f(x - h)}{2h}
$$

Taking $x = 6$ and $h = 0.05$

$$
f'_{\rm fd}(6) \approx -0.0121218
$$

Using the actual function to calculate the derivative you get

$$
f'(6) = -0.0121202 = -\left.\frac{24x}{(1 + 3x^2)^2}\right|_{x= 6}
$$

The relative error is

$$
\epsilon = 1 - \frac{f_{\rm fd}(6)}{f'(6)} = 0.000135
$$